# how to fix None fields as false in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
       Id      0     1     2     3     4     5
0   apple   True  None  None  None  None  None
1  orange  False  None  True  None  None  None
2  banana   True  None  None  True  None  None
3   guava  False  None  None  None  True  None
4  leeche   None  True  None  None  None  None
```

above dataframe contains boolean and None value
If any of 0-5 columns have false i want to omit them from updated dataframe. considering None denotes True value , so my result should look like

```
           Id      
0         apple       
2         banana        
4         leeche
```

I am not able to understand how to get combined filter on multiple columns.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
cols = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
df = df.loc[df[cols].ne('False').all(1), ['Id']]
#if False is boolean
#df = df.loc[df[cols].ne(False).all(1), ['Id']]
print (df)
       Id
0   apple
2  banana
4  leeche
```

If need check all columns without first:

```
df = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].ne('False').all(1), ['Id']]
```

**Explanation**:

First select columns by columns names:

```
#if strings
cols = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
#if numeric 
#cols = np.arange(6)
print (df[cols])
       0     1     2     3     4     5
0   True  None  None  None  None  None
1  False  None  True  None  None  None
2   True  None  None  True  None  None
3  False  None  None  None  True  None
4   None  True  None  None  None  None
```

Then check if not equal `False` by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html):

```
#if boolean False
print(df[cols].ne(False))
#if string False
#print(df[cols].ne('False'))
       0     1     2     3     4     5
0   True  True  True  True  True  True
1  False  True  True  True  True  True
2   True  True  True  True  True  True
3  False  True  True  True  True  True
4   True  True  True  True  True  True
```

And test if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print(df[cols].ne('False').all(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Last filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with select `Id` with `[]` for one column `DataFrame`:

```
print(df[df[cols].ne('False').all(1)])
       Id     0     1     2     3     4     5
0   apple  True  None  None  None  None  None
2  banana  True  None  None  True  None  None
4  leeche  None  True  None  None  None  None

print(df.loc[df[cols].ne('False').all(1), ['Id']])
       Id
0   apple
2  banana
4  leeche
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening here

Comment: @sbasu - Edited answer.